# Android In-App Billing vs. GCM Permissions

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-cloud-messaging

When you add Android GCM to an app, [the documentation says](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html#android-app) "Declare and use a custom permission so only this application can receive GCM messages".

The Android In-app Billing sample app is not configured with this type of custom permission.

Why not?  What is different about Android IAB and GCM that makes the custom permission necessary for the latter but not for the former?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android in-app billing infrastructure does not make unsolicited calls into your app. GCM, on the other hand, does.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I was hoping for a bit more technical detail.  IAB also has asynch responses.  The GCM (and C2DM before it) docs seem to indicate that the custom permission is needed to defeat man in the middle attacks. I noticed that GCM does not require the custom permission for 4.1 and above... maybe this is simply a legacy requirement and they have a better way of doing things now which they take advantage of in IAB?

Comment: IAB has means for authenticating the payload from inside the app - a signature check. So man in the middle is not a problem. GCM has no such thing.